# How to create Hive connection in airflow to specific DB?

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

I am trying to create Hive connection in airflow to point to specific Database. I tried to find the params in HiveHook and tried the below in the extra options.

```
{"db":"test_base"}  {"schema":"test_base"} and {"database":"test_base"}
```

But looks like nothing works and always points to default db.

could someone help me to pointout what are the possible parameters we can pass in extra_options ?

Comment: What version of `Airflow` are you using? If its `HiveServer2Hook` you are referring to, then at least `v1.10` (apparently) [should work fine](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/hooks/hive_hooks.py#L773). Even `HiveCliHook` takes care of `schema` in [while running `HQL` statement](https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v1-10-stable/airflow/hooks/hive_hooks.py#L183)

Comment: Otherwise you could always resort to prefixing table-name with name of database (schema) like this `SELECT * FROM db_name.table_name;` in your `HQL` statement (though that might not be very convenient)